# Theorem titles in outer margins (even / odd pages)

Tags: ntheorem, thmtools, autoref

I would like theorem / definition / etc. labels to appear in the *outer* page margin (taking even and odd pages into account). First, I tried to use the `thmtools` package (code and image below). However, I only managed to place the label always in the left margin. In particular, I've got no idea how to combine `thmtools` with `ifoddpage`.

Next, I tried `ntheorem` (code and image below). With `ntheorem`, the label placement worked as it should, but I was unable to change the font style of the title of the theorem ("Some Important Theorem" in the images below) and place it on a line of its own. In addition, I couldn't get rid of the indentation. Finally, it also broke my `autoref` references.

To **summarize**: What I'm looking for is a theorem environment which allows

- labels in *outer* page margins (odd / even pages)
- full styling control for labels, title and body
- `autoref` compatibility (in particular, I would like to use a single counter for different theorem environments such as Theorem, Definition, etc.)

I'm about to give up, so I really hope someone can help me with this.

Code for `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.25in, outer=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newlength{\spaceblength}
\settowidth{\spaceblength}{\bfseries\ }
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={}{\\[\parskip]}, % Braces for additional text
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    headformat={%
        \makebox[0pt][r]{\color{red}\NAME\ \NUMBER\ \ }\hskip-\spaceblength{\NOTE}%
    }
]{boxstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=boxstyle,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\newpage

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Code for `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.25in, outer=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\makeatletter%
\newtheoremstyle{nonumoutermargin}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont {\hskip18pt##1}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1}\hskip6pt}\fi]}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont   {\hskip18pt##1}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1}\hskip6pt}\fi##3]}

\newtheoremstyle{outermargin}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont {\hskip18pt##1\hskip\labelsep##2}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1\hskip\labelsep##2}\hskip6pt}\fi]}%
{\item[\checkoddpage\ifoddpageoroneside\rlap{\hskip\linewidth\theorem@headerfont{\hskip18pt##1\hskip\labelsep##2}}%
\else\llap{\theorem@headerfont{##1\hskip\labelsep##2}\hskip6pt}\fi##3]}
\makeatother

\theoremindent=0pt
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries\color{red}}
\theoremstyle{outermargin}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\newpage

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I continued looking for an answer and the following worked for me (I thought I had tried that before and it didn't compile...):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.25in, outer=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newlength{\spaceblength}
\settowidth{\spaceblength}{\bfseries\ }
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries,
    notebraces={}{\\[\parskip]}, % Braces for additional text
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    headformat={%
        \checkoddpage\ifoddpage\rlap{\hskip\textwidth\color{red}\ \ \ \NAME\ \NUMBER}\hskip-\spaceblength{\NOTE}%
        \else\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{red}\NAME\ \NUMBER\ \ \ }\hskip-\spaceblength{\NOTE}\fi%
    },
]{boxstyle}

\declaretheorem[style=boxstyle,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\newpage

\begin{theorem}[Some Important Theorem]
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.

    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
    This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem. This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```